# Ruby doesn't get interpreted in a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

i got this code:

```
= link_to main_app.dashboard_path(current_user), :class => 'class1 #{ is_active_link?("dashboard") }' do
  %p
    Dashboard
```

Ya and is_active_link? doesn`t get executed. Why? It just interprets as plain string!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ruby, strings are only interpolated if they are double-quoted. Single-quoted strings are literal strings (they do not have this behaviour). Try this:

```
= link_to main_app.dashboard_path(current_user), :class => "class1 #{ is_active_link?('dashboard') }" do
  %p
    Dashboard
```

Comment: You made my day will accept the answer as soon as stackoverflow let me :)